# how to view the spinning wheel in mobile properly

Tags: jquery, mobile

I am doing a site to view from mobile . I done a spinning wheel in it. My problem is i have done the site in percentage but i can't make this `spinning wheel` in percentage. Now the portion of spinning wheel looks as broken. how can i tackle this problem .

I got the spinning wheel from the site:

> http://iroylabs.blogspot.in/2011/06/latest-jquery-plugin.html

I have uploaded the spinning wheel:

> http://rapidsurfing.net/mivotv/spin-wheel/spin-wheel.html

please somebody help any help will be appeciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do some JS code to resize the spin wheel according to the device screen, something like this:

```
var size = screen.width - 20px;
$('.canvas').css({
  width: size,
  height: size
});
```